# pytorch passing architecture type with argprse

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, argparse, pytorch

Using Pytorch. When passing architecture type by using the following code:

```
parser.add_argument('-arch', action='store',
                    dest='arch',
                    default= str('vgg16'))
```

When using the name of the architecture with the following code:

```
model = models.__dict__['{!r}'.format(results.arch)](pretrained=True)
```

I get the following error:

> model = models.**dict**'{!r}'.format(results.arch)
>   KeyError: "'vgg16'"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got [`KeyError`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError) meaning your imported `models` do not include `'vgg16'` as one of the known models.
Check what models you do have by printing

```
print(models.__dict__.keys())
```

This should allow you to know what models you import and which are missing, then you can look into your imports and see where `'vgg16'` got lost.

Comment: vgg16 does exist in the list. I think that the problem is that I`m passing  "'vgg16'" instead of ``vgg16``. extra quotes

Comment: @DarioFederici does it exists as `'vgg16'` or `"'vgg16'"` (note the extra quotation marks) this is what the `!r` format string is doing, you might need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
model = models.__dict__[results.arch](pretrained=True)
```

Solution.